# Polar cone and set addition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R^n}$, $T\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be nonempty closed convex cones.

Define $C^*=\{ y\in \mathbb{R^n} | y\cdot x \leq 0, \forall x \in C\}$

I am trying to show $S^* + T^* \subset (S\cap T)^*$, where + is set addition.

I don't even know how to start...

Please give me some hint. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of grinding through the definitions:

Suppose $\sigma \in S^*, \tau \in T^*$.

Suppose $x \in S \cap T$, then $\sigma \cdot x \le 0$, $\tau \cdot x \le 0$ and so $\sigma \cdot x + \tau \cdot x = ( \sigma + \tau )\cdot x \le 0$,
and so $\sigma + \tau  \in (S \cap T)^*$.